# Can I set colors in an Excel bar chart tied to dynamic data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors

I have a bar chart that is tied to some data that changes quarter to quarter. I have the data set up to sort automatically.

I would like it so that, for example, the bar for `City` is is always purple and the bar for `street` is always blue and all other bars are green.

The issue is, when the data sorts, the colors don’t stay with what is set. IE the top is always purple regardless of if it is city, street, or other category unless I manually change it.

If it helps, my data automatically sorts largest to smallest based on the second column, which is the counts.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: I have an idea, but I'd like to see a screenshot of your data and chart before I propose it.

Answer (score 0):

For Pivot Charts where you are sorting the order of fields, this can be stopped by navigating to File > Options > Advanced > Chart, and:

- deselect 'Properties follow chart data point for current workbook'
- [optionally] deselect 'Properties follow chart data point for all new workbooks'

I ended up recreating the chart to clear out cached color settings, but then it stopped resetting on sort.

---

To work around colors resetting on filter or slicer changes, check out: https://peltiertech.com/pivot-chart-formatting-changes/